# How can I send remote emails using exim?

Tags: debian, smtp, exim, rkhunter

I'm on Debian I'm trying to send an email to email@gmail.com but it's not working although I changed the `configtype` in `update-exim4.conf.conf`  to "internet".

It doesn't give me any output but I can't find anything in the email@gmail.com

The error log shows this:

> The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to\n550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your\n550-5.7.1 service provider

Comment: I use the command :
mail -s "Hello" email@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your log entry, its clear that your IP is not authorized to send emails from the server you are sending this email.

Here are the details of the issue:

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10336